# enable chrome extension via .cmd script?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is it possible to enable one specific extension in Chrome, automatically using the .cmd script?  The extension is already installed (from chrome-store), I need to enable it every morning at 9:00.

Comment: I'm going to assume Windows based on '.CMD', but can you confirm? Are you talking about Windows?  What have you tried already?

Comment: Win7. Chrome 39. I mean to enable 1 extension by command-line for example http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: or to copy some file (over-write) in C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Comment: or regedit  any thread in registry??

Answer (score 0):

There is a *plain text* file named `Preferences` (contains `JSON` markup) and which every Chromium / Google Chrome user will have [in their own user directory](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Google_Chrome). In this file there is nearly all about extensions.

But `Preferences` get copied from `master_preferences` only once and **are not editable** after! However, if you would like **violate** it, pay your attention to 
`known_disabled` and `disable_reasons` keywords there (this enumeration could be not complete), but do not attempt change it while Chrome is running...